# How can I remove a specific index from an array and then insert a new one on that same index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to do one thing but I have 2 choices

1. Remove a specific item/index from an array and then insert a new one in that same index.
2. Do not remove the item but edit it with new data.

I have this piece of code:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
      if (qs[i].id === getNewQ.id) {
        const qsCopy = [...qs].filter((q) => q.id !== getNewQ.id);

        return [...qsCopy, { ...newGroup }];
      }
    }

    return [...qs];
  };
```

It removes the item from the array, but when it adds the new item, it adds it to the last index. But what I need, is this new item to be added to the index where the other item was removed.

Is it clear?

I created a reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-darwin-4tty0?file=/src/App.tsx:912-1171

In the sample, you will notice how the new item gets added to the last index. It needs to be as generic as possible because it is dynamic. Not all the time would be the same index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map the `qs` instead, and when the ID matches, return the `newGroup` instead of the previous item in state:

```
const handleClick = () => qs.map((q) => (
  q.id === getNewQ.id
    ? { ...newGroup }
    : q
));
```

Comment: `qs.map` returns a new modified array. You will need to reassign the `qs` variable.
Eg: `qs = qs.map(...)`, If you want to keep the same variable!

Comment: I don't think so, OP's current code does not reassign `qs`, it only returns a new array. Similarly, my code doesn't reassign `qs`, but returns something new. (and even then, it's good to avoid reassignment when not necessary)

Comment: Is this a mutation? I am using react `useState` so at the end your solution looks like this: `addItems(qs => [...qs.map(q => (q.id === getClickedQuestion.id ? { ...newGroup } : q))])`, is that ok? I think it must not mutate the data. Right now, the solution works perfectly.

Comment: There is no mutation in my answer. `.map` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the old one. So you do not need to spread the result of `.map`. You probably don't need to spread `newGroup` either - you may well be able to `? newGroup` instead

Answer (score 1):

To avoid iterating over the whole array use findIndex as follow

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const qsCopy = [...qs];
  const itemIndex = qs.findIndex(({ id }) => (id === getNewQ.id));

  if (itemIndex !== -1) {
    qsCopy[itemIndex] = { ...newGroup };
  }

  return qsCopy;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

CertainPerformance provided a good solution allowing you to only foreach your array once.

Just for informations maybe would be useful for other people:

There are other ways to do it as well
You could have done a find of your object and then add your properties.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
Like:

```
const myObject = qs.find(q => q.id === myId)
```

But a spread wouldn't have worked because it would create another object.

Another possibility: A findIndex and a splice if needed

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex